# Call 'bar' once, after 'foo' has been called multiple times within specific time

Tags: python, python-2.7

Assume you have an event driven program that monitors value changes of all variables on a server. Every time a change is monitored `foo` is called.

```
def foo(self, var_name, new_val):
    print var_name, " has new value: ", new_val
```

After `foo` is called, I would like to call `bar`

```
def bar(self):
    print "Hello world!"
```

However, if multiple variables change their values within a short period of time, say 100 ms, `bar` should only be called once.

To clarify, assume we have variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. Here are two desired outputs...

Only `a` changes value within 100 ms.

```
a has new value: 4
Hello world!
```

All variables change value within 100 ms.

```
a has new value: 4
b has new value: 4
c has new value: 4
d has new value: 4
Hello world!
```

How can this be accomplished? All help is much appreciated!

Comment: _When_ should `bar` be called? Should the call sequence be like `foo, bar, foo, foo, foo` or `foo, foo, foo, foo, bar`?

Comment: Set a timer and call `bar` every 100ms *if* `foo` has been called at least once in that period.

Comment: Are you running using threads or asyncio or such? Otherwise debouncing (Google keyword!) with a timeout will be tough…

Comment: @Rawing, `bar` should always be called last.

Comment: @EvilTak, how do I check that foo has been called without ugly global bools and functions keeping time etc.

Comment: @deceze, event driven

Comment: Then I can only describe a general debounce implementation: when `foo` is called, start a timeout to call `bar` after *x* seconds; when `foo` is called again clear the previous timeout and start a new one.

Comment: @deceze take a situation where the timeout interval is 100 ms, and a value is changed every 90 ms (any period less than the interval works here). `bar` will never be called, as the call keeps getting deferred every time `foo` is called.

Comment: @JCKaz you can extract the timekeeping to a class, but that's the best you can do. You will have to keep time some way or the other, and the best way is to let a `Timer` (or similar) class do the work for you.

Comment: @Evil It's not hard to augment that basic debouncing with another rule that places a maximum timeout between calls as well to avoid that. It really depends on what exactly OP means by "calling last".

Comment: I actually found a simple solution: However, it involves twisted's `callLater()` (I was already using twisted). My solution does not demand any new imports. Please comment if I should "answer my own question" or if I should delete this entire post. The first decision to reach 3 votes will be invoked. Vote below:

Comment: Answer own question

Comment: Answer, so that others having the same question won't need to ask the question again or ping this post for the full solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your event loop, you'll have to track time intervals of length `INTERVAL` (e.g. 100ms) and call `bar` at the end of every interval if `foo` was called in that interval. Since `foo` is called when a change is monitored, you can simplify the condition to calling `bar` if a change was performed in that time interval.

```
import time

INTERVAL = 0.1      # 100 ms
previous_call_time = time.time()
value_changed_in_interval = False

# Event loop
while True:
    if time.time() - previous_call_time >= INTERVAL:
        # Time to call bar
        previous_call_time = time.time()

        if value_changed_in_interval:
            bar()

        # Reset, since we have started a new interval
        value_changed_in_interval = False

    # Check for changes and send events
    # If a value was changed, set value_changed_in_interval to True
```

Comment: This can also easily lead to the call sequence `foo, bar, foo, foo, foo, bar`…

Comment: `<= INTERVAL` should be `>= INTERVAL`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Rawing yes, it should be.